# Powershell: How to list files (and get their info) on USB devices that don't have a file system (MTP and PTP)?

Tags: powershell

I'm getting connected MTP devices with the following command:

```
(((New-Object -com Shell.Application).NameSpace(17)).Items() | where { $_.type -eq 'Portable Media Player' }).GetFolder
```

`.NameSpace(17)` means This PC

Output:

```
Title                      : Samsung_S20
Application                : System.__ComObject
Parent                     :
ParentFolder               : System.__ComObject
Self                       : System.__ComObject
OfflineStatus              :
HaveToShowWebViewBarricade : False
ShowWebViewBarricade       : False
```

If I call `.Items()` on that object, I get the following output:

```
(((New-Object -com Shell.Application).NameSpace(17)).Items() | where { $_.type -eq 'Portable Media Player' }).GetFolder.Items()
```

```
Application  : System.__ComObject
Parent       : System.__ComObject
Name         : Phone storage
Path         : ::{12D04FE0-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30305A}\\\?\usb#vid_0e8d&pid_2008#0123456789abcdef#{5bc27878-a6fa-4155-ba85-f98f491d4f24}\SID-{
               10001,,4180500480}
GetLink      :
GetFolder    : System.__ComObject
IsLink       : False
IsFolder     : True
IsFileSystem : False
IsBrowsable  : False
ModifyDate   : 12/30/1899 00:00:00
Size         : 0
Type         : Generic hierarchical
```

In the File Explorer I can see that the `Phone storage` is indeed  the root directory on that device and when I open it I can see all the device's directories like DCIM, Android, Pictures.

However I cannot find a way to navigate the directory further than `.\Phone storage\` and see this list of directories using powershell.

I can get the full path with this command:

```
(((New-Object -com Shell.Application).NameSpace(17)).Items() | where { $_.type -eq 'Portable Media Player' }).GetFolder.Self.Path
```

But I don't know if powershell exposes any methods that File Explorer uses to navigate / stat such paths.

Comment: Can you just not use `Get-ChildItem`?

Comment: if I add `Get-ChildItem` at the beginning of the command, I get `Cannot find path 'C:\Users\username\System.__ComObject' because it does not exist.`. I'm not sure Get-ChildItem can read directories without file system

Comment: You need to expand that object bring returned. Is that really the path that's returned?

Comment: The command returns the output that I shown above. I'm not sure how to expand it. I has a path property `::{12D04FE0-3AEA....` but if I return it to `Get-ChildItem` I get a similar error

Comment: What does `.GetFolder` return

Comment: I edited the post, added the output

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236257/discussion-between-abraham-zinala-and-alekseyhoffman).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost there. You can not use PowerShell cmdlets to browse MTP devices. You have to use the shell objects, their methods, and properties.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/objects

Continuing with your example, the next step is to get the folder object of your phone's root directory.

```
$phone_item = (((New-Object -com Shell.Application).NameSpace(17)).Items() | where { $_.type -eq 'Portable Media Player' })

# This gets the root folder as an FolderItem object
$phone_root_item = $phone_item.GetFolder().Items() | where { $_.Name -eq "Phone storage" }

# Turn the FolderItem object into a Folder object
$phone_root_folder = $phone_root_item.GetFolder()
```

From this point you can use `$phone_root_folder` to browse.

This gets the Camera folder as a FolderItem object.

```
PS C:\> $test_item = $phone_root_folder.ParseName("DCIM\Camera")
PS C:\> $test_item.Name
Camera
PS C:\> $test_item.IsFolder()
True
```

You can use GetFolder(), items(), and item() to examine the folder

```
PS C:\> $test_folder = $test_item.GetFolder()
PS C:\> $test_folder.items().count
378
PS C:\> ($test_folder.items() | select -first 1).Name
20221126_143637_018
PS C:\> $test_folder.items().item(0).Name
20221126_143637_018
```

If you know a folder or file's path, you can retrieve its FolderItem object directly.

```
PS C:\> $test_item = $phone_root_folder.ParseName("DCIM\Camera\20221126_143637_018.jpg")
PS C:\> $test_item.Name
20221126_143637_018
PS C:\> $test_item.Type
JPG File
```